# Subscription Buttons. Initial Payment instead of Trial?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I've read that there's an option, when setting recurring payments (specifically subscriptions), to include an initial payment, but I'm only seeing a "trial period".

I can't use the trial period, because there's no guarantee that users will continue with the subscription after the trial period is over.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Subscription button doesn't support for initial payment. You may have another option to creating recurring profiles by Paypal classic API(Express checkout + CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile). 
You could optionally specify an initial payment by INITAMT field when creating the recurring profile.
See the integration guide [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ECDGRecurringPayments/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to happen can vary depending on the product that you are referring to.

It sounds like you are referring to subscription buttons. With the buttons you **can** offer a trial period, but if you leave that unchecked, it will charge your customer right away, the amount you set per billing cycle.

If you are using **PayPal Payments Pro** with recurring billing, you will have more flexible option to charge buyers per month. You can change the amounts, trial periods, length of billing cycle etc.

Here is a link to the developer guide on [PayPal Recurring Payments.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've reviewed that guide, but it didn't touch on what I need. What you've recommended is what I'm already doing. I had no choice but to use the "trial period" option. The problem is I'm not looking for a "trial period", but an "initial payment". The trial period gives the option to opt out of the following recurring payments. Can you help?

Comment: No problem! Just leave the trial option unchecked when you create the button and it will charge your buyer right away.